# Bus Error when writing to mmaped data

Tags: c, shared-memory, mmap, bus-error

When I first made this project last semester, the code worked fine. Now I get a bus error when the mmapped memory to share between processes is being written to and I'm not sure why it is not working anymore.

```
Account_Info *mapData()
{
    int fd;
    //open/create file with read and write permission and check return value
    if ((fd = open("accounts", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0644)) == -1)
    {
            perror("Unable to open account list file.");
            exit(0);
    }

    //map data to be shared with different processes
    Account_Info *accounts = mmap((void*)0, (size_t) 100*(sizeof(Account_Info)), PROT_WRITE,
    MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    int count= 0;

    //loop to initialize values of Account_Info struct
    while (count != 20)
    {
            //bus error occurs here
            accounts[count].CurrBalance= 0;
            accounts[count].flag = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while (i != 100)
            {
                    //place NULL terminator into each element of AccName
                    accounts[count].AccName[i]= '\0';
                    i++;
            }

            count++;
    }

    close(fd);
    return accounts;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A documented cause for SIGBUS with mmap is

> Attempted  access to a portion of the buffer that does not correspond to the file (for example, beyond the end of the file, including the case where another process has truncated the file).

My guess is that the `accounts` file didn't exist, so `open` with `O_CREAT` created it. But it has zero size, so any attempt to read or write through the mapping will fault. You need to fill the file with enough zeroes (or something else) to cover the mapping, for example using `ftruncate`.

Answer (score 2):

You will get `SIGBUS` if you attempt to write past the mapped region of the file.

Chances are pretty good that your backing store file `accounts` is truncated/too short. (e.g.) if the file has space for 10 struct entries and you write to the 11th, you'll get `SIGBUS`

Do an `fstat` to get `st_size` and compare this against the length parameter you're giving to `mmap`

You may want to consider using `ftruncate` to extend the file before doing `mmap`